# 1D Ising Model Graph and Configuration

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a problem with this Python code I've written. It looks good, I get no errors and it runs. However, it doesn't stop running, which leads me to assume it must be stuck on some infinite loop of some sort. When I stop the running I get the most recent call as being elif rand() < np.exp(-cost*beta):, every time. So I assumed that this was where the problem was. But, I can't find any problems with it. Any help would be appreciated, my code is simulating and graphing the 1D Ising chain Model in quantum and statistical mechanics.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

#The 1D Ising Model
#MC (or mc) is just short for Monte Carlo throughout the code
#This code will look the same as the code for the 2D Ising model code, just changing variables to get a result that is 2-dimensional
def initialstate(N): #This will generate a random spin configuration for initial condition as mentioned in section 4.11
    state = 2*np.random.randint(2, size=(N))-1
    return state

def mcmove(config, beta, N): #This is the Monte Carlo move using Metropolis algorithm talked about in the textbook section 4.11
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            a = np.random.randint(0, N)
            s = config[a]
            nb = config[(a+1)%N] + config[(a-1)%N] #%N allows for toroidal boundary conditions
            cost = 2*s*nb
            if cost < 0:
                s *= -1
            elif rand() < np.exp(-cost*beta):
                config[a] = s
    return config
    print(config)


def calculateEnergy(config, N): #This is the energy of a given configuration
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(config)):
        for j in range(len(config)):
            S = config[i]
            nb = config[(i+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N]
            energy += -nb * S
    return energy/2 #divides the resultinng energy by 4

def calculateMagnetization(config): #This is the magnetization of the given configuration
    magnetization = np.sum(config) #The magnetization is just a sum
    return magnetization

def main():

#The following will be the parameters
    N_T = 100 #This is the number of temperature points
    N = 200 #This will be the size of the lattice
    equilsteps = 1000 #Number of Monte Carlo sweeps for equilibration
    mcsteps = 1000 #Number of Monte Carlo sweeps for calculation

    T = np.linspace(1.01, 3.28, N_T);
    E,M,C,X = np.zeros(N_T), np.zeros(N_T), np.zeros(N_T), np.zeros(N_T) #Energy (E), Magnetization (M), Specific Heat (C), and Susceptibility (X)
    n_1, n_2 = (1.0)/(mcsteps*N), (1.0)/(mcsteps*mcsteps*N)

    for tt in range(N_T):
        E_1 = M_1 = E_2 = M_2 = 0
        config = initialstate(N)
        i_T = 1.0/T[tt]; i_T_2 = i_T*i_T;

        for i in range(equilsteps): #This is the equilibrate
            mcmove(config, i_T, N)
            Energy = calculateEnergy(config, N) #defined above, which will calculate the energy
            Magnet = calculateMagnetization(config) #also defined above, will calculate the magnetization

            M_1 = M_1 + Magnet
            E_1 = E_1 + Energy
            M_2 = M_2 + Magnet*Magnet
            E_2 = E_2 + Energy*Energy

        E[tt] = n_1*E_1 #Energy
        M[tt] = n_1*M_1 #Magnetization
        C[tt] = (n_1*E_2 - n_2*E_1*E_1)*i_T_2 #Specific Heat
        X[tt] = (n_1*M_2 - n_2*M_1*M_1)*i_T #Susceptibility

    f = plt.figure(figsize = (18, 10)); #This will plot the calculated values

#This will be for the Energy
    f.add_subplot(2, 2, 1);
    plt.scatter(T, E, s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'g') #This will plot the energy values vs temperature on a scatter plot
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (kT/J)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the x-axis
    plt.ylabel("Energy (E/NJ)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the y-axis
    plt.axis('tight');

#This will be for the Magnetization
    f.add_subplot(2, 2, 2);
    plt.scatter(T, M, s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'r') #This will plot the magnetization values vs temperature on a scatter plot
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (kT/J)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the x-axis
    plt.ylabel("Magnetization (M(T))", fontsize = 15); #This labels the y-axis
    plt.axis('tight');

#This will be for the Specific Heat
    f.add_subplot(2, 2, 3);
    plt.scatter(T, C, s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'g') #This will plot the specific heat values vs temperature on a scatter plot
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (kT/J)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the x-axis
    plt.ylabel("Specific Heat (C/Nk)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the y-axis
    plt.axis('tight');

#This will be for the Susceptibility
    f.add_subplot(2, 2, 4);
    plt.scatter(T, X, s=50, marker = 'o', color = 'r') #This will plot the susceptibility values vs temperature on a scatter plot
    plt.xlabel("Temperature (kT/J)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the x-axis
    plt.ylabel("Susceptibility (X)", fontsize = 15); #This labels the y-axis
    plt.axis('tight');

    plt.show()

main()
```

Comment: Does the plot show in a separate window? If so, does the script stop when that window is closed?

Comment: I seriously have no idea, I had my friend run it on his Mac OS terminal and it plotted and ran properly. For some reason Spyder doesn't seem to agree with the format of my code.

Comment: Depending on how your Spyder is configured to display matplotlib (check preferences) imshow() might be acting as your infinite loop. Try replacing the `plt.imshow()` with a `plt.save_fig('path/to/save.png')`.

Comment: I checked preferences and couldn't find this imshow() you are talking about. However I did change the way graphs would be displayed, instead of being 'inline' I set it to automatic.

Comment: I'm sorry not `plt.imshow()` but `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using two nested for loops in mcmove function. It takes longer (N squared) times to run for large monte carlo steps. You original code do stop after a long time. But since you are using 1D Ising model, you need to use one for loop. It will significantly reduce you computational time.